# HDF Data File Format Validator

Tags: python, python-3.x, console

As part of a [personal project I am working on](https://github.com/rudikershaw/fire-emissions-ai) in python, I have started writing a command line utility to convert `.hdf` files into a `JSON` file. Before the conversion is done however, I have written some validation code to check that the file exists, has the correct extension, and has the correct basic format.

Here is the code so far

```
import sys
import h5py
from pathlib import Path

# -------------------------------------------------
# Utility classes defined below.
# -------------------------------------------------
class Validator:
    def print_help_text():
        print("The processor.py utility is designed to take a single argument, the path")
        print("to a NASA EarthData Global Fire Emissions Database GFED4.1s_yyyy.hdf5 file.")
        print("Example - $ ./preprocess.py some/directory/GFED4.1s_2015.hdf5\n")

        print("If a valid file path is passed to the utility it should output individual JSO")
        print("files for each month, that contain data in the format required to train the")
        print("emissions predictor.\n")

        print("By default the new files will be ouput to the same directory that contains")
        print("the script. Alternatively, you can provide a second argument with a path to")
        print("another directory for the output files to be placed in.")


    def valid_hdf_file(path_string):
        valid_extensions = ("hdf","hdf4","hdf5","h4","h5", "he2", "he5")
        if path_string.split(".")[-1] in valid_extensions:
            if Path(path_string).is_file():
                return True
            else:
                print("\n'" + path_string + "' is not a valid file.\n")
                return False
        else:
            print("\nThe input file must be an HDF file with a correct extension.\n")
            return False


    def valid_arguments(arguements):
        args = len(arguements)
        if (args == 2 or args == 3) and arguements[1] != "--help":
            path_to_data = arguements[1]
            return Validator.valid_hdf_file(path_to_data)
        else:
            Validator.print_help_text()
            return False


    def valid_leaf_groups(group, month, hdf_file):
        groups_and_leaves = {
            "biosphere": ("BB", "NPP", "Rh"),
            "burned_area": ("burned_fraction",),
            "emissions": ("C", "DM")
        }
        valid = True
        for leaf in groups_and_leaves[group]:
             full_group = group + "/" + ("%02d" % month) + "/" + leaf
            if full_group not in hdf_file:
                valid = False
                print("Expected group '" + full_group + "' not in HDF file.")
        return valid


    def valid_hdf_structure(hdf_file):
        valid = True
        for group in ("ancill/basis_regions", "lon", "lat"):
            if group not in hdf_file:
                valid = False
                print("Expected group '" + group + "' not in HDF file.")
        for group in ("biosphere", "burned_area", "emissions"):
            for month in range(1,13):
                full_group = group + "/" + ("%02d" % month)
                if full_group not in hdf_file:
                    valid = False
                    print("Expected group '" + full_group + "' not in HDF file.")
                else:
                    valid = valid and Validator.valid_leaf_groups(group, month, hdf_file)
        return valid

# -------------------------------------------------
# Script starts here.
# -------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not Validator.valid_arguments(sys.argv):
        sys.exit()

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    print("Processing - " + filename)
    hdf_file = h5py.File(filename, 'r')

    if not Validator.valid_hdf_structure(hdf_file):
        sys.exit()    

    print("Basic structure of hdf file confirmed to conform to GFED4 format.")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments on your code.  In no particular order:

#### Blocks of text, should be blocks of text

Instead of a bunch of print statements, consider using one block of text, and a loop like:

```
  def print_help_text():
      help_text = """
          The processor.py utility is designed to take a single argument, the path
          to a NASA EarthData Global Fire Emissions Database GFED4.1s_yyyy.hdf5 file.
          Example - $ ./preprocess.py some/directory/GFED4.1s_2015.hdf5

          If a valid file path is passed to the utility it should output individual JSO
          files for each month, that contain data in the format required to train the
          emissions predictor."

          By default the new files will be ouput to the same directory that contains
          the script. Alternatively, you can provide a second argument with a path to
          another directory for the output files to be placed in.
      """
      for line in help_text.split()[1:-1]:
          print(line.strip())
```

#### `in` is handy

I would prefer to see this:

```
args = len(arguements)
if (args == 2 or args == 3) and arguements[1] != "--help":
    ...
```

as this:

```
if len(arguements) in (2, 3) and arguements[1] != "--help":
     ...
```

This construct makes it more obvious that you are looking for the length to be one of a specific list of values.

#### @staticmethod

Your Validator class has a bunch of staticmethods, but they are not declared as such. This is not terribly pythonic.  I suggest you investigate: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I confess I didn't know the difference between `@staticmethod` and just not passing `self`.  Can I ask the reason for printing the sting block one line at a time like that? Why not just print the full block in one go if it is all in one string?

Comment: The key is that the print does a `.strip()` to remove the leading spaces.  You could format the block without the leading spaces, but I find that harder to read, and the code in the `for` loop is not hard to write or understand.

Comment: FYI, I had some issues with the loop in the end, so I swapped it out for a regex replace `print(re.sub(" +", " ", help_text))` which I actually think is neater too.

Comment: @RudiKershaw There is also [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

#### Unnecessary comments

> ```
> # -------------------------------------------------
> # Utility classes defined below.
> # -------------------------------------------------
>
> class Validator:
>     […]
> ```

This comment is inaccurate (there is only one class), and unnecessary in two ways:

- The reader can already see that there is a class definition below, no need to point that out in comments.
- The class itself is unnecessary (see below).

> ```
> # -------------------------------------------------
> # Script starts here.
> # -------------------------------------------------
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     […]
> ```

The same for this comment, `if __name__ == "__main__"` already tells the reader that the script starts here.

#### Unnecessary class

The `Validator` class is a [*pseudo class*](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf), for which there are several indicators:

- The class name is vague. If the class had a real purpose, it would be relatively easy to find a good name for it.
- It is not useful to make an instance of the class (and in fact, there is no instance), instead it only serves as a namespace for some functions. In Python, a module already fulfills this purpose.
- The functions contained in the class are not closely related. Checking the command line arguments and printing a help text is a different concern than inspecting the structure of the file contents.

The class should be removed and the class methods should become free functions.

#### Unnecessary file checks

I don't think it is useful to test whether the filename has one of a number of predefined extensions. Either the the *contents* of the file are valid, then the filename doesn't matter. Or the contents are not valid, then the filename also doesn't matter.

Also, checking whether the file exists is not necessary, `h5py.File` will do that:

```
>>> h5py.File('non-existent-file', 'r')
[…]
OSError: Unable to open file (…, error message = 'no such file or directory', …)
>>> h5py.File('some-directory', 'r')
[…]
OSError: Unable to open file (…, error message = 'is a directory', …)
```

#### Spelling

There are several spelling mistakes in the code (e.g. `JSON` → `JSO`, `output` → `ouput`, `arguments` → `arguements`).

Spelling mistakes can indicate lack of attention to detail, which is particularly important in programming, so be careful.

#### Command line interface

According to the description, `The processor.py utility is designed to take a single argument, the path`, yet the number of arguments is checked as `args == 2 or args == 3`. <strike>I don't understand why a second arguments is allowed.</strike> A second argument (`args == 3`) is allowed, but currently not used.

Instead of manually checking the arguments and printing a help text, consider using a library like [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to do that for you.

The help text should be made into a docstring of the module, to make it accessible to the Python [help utilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) (e.g. the `help()` function and the `pydoc` command line tool).

#### Error flags

Instead of juggling with error flags, use exceptions. [It is more Pythonic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630706/best-practice-in-python-for-return-value-on-error-vs-success)

#### Suggested code

I would write the code like this:

```
"""Check the validity of a NASA EarthData Global Fire Emissions Database
GFED4.1s_yyyy.hdf5 file and output individual JSON files for each month that
contains data in the format required to train the emissions predictor.

By default, the new files will be output to the same directory that contains
the script. Alternatively, another directory name can be provided for the
output files to be placed in.
"""

import h5py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, RawTextHelpFormatter

class MissingGroup(Exception):
    """Raised when an expected group is missing in an HDF file."""
    def __init__(self, group):
        Exception.__init__(self,
            "Group '{}' missing in HDF file.".format(group)
        )

def check_leaf_groups(group, month, hdf_file):
    """Check if all expected leaf groups for the given month exist.

    MissingGroup is raised if a group is missing.
    """
    groups_and_leaves = {
        "biosphere": ("BB", "NPP", "Rh"),
        "burned_area": ("burned_fraction",),
        "emissions": ("C", "DM")
    }
    for leaf in groups_and_leaves[group]:
        full_group = '{}/{:02d}/{}'.format(group, month, leaf)
        if full_group not in hdf_file:
            raise MissingGroup(full_group)


def check_hdf_structure(hdf_file):
    """Check if all expected groups exist in the HDF file.

    MissingGroup is raised if a group is missing.
    """
    for group in ("ancill/basis_regions", "lon", "lat"):
        if group not in hdf_file:
            raise MissingGroup(group)
    for group in ("biosphere", "burned_area", "emissions"):
        for month in range(1,13):
            full_group = '{}/{:02d}'.format(group, month)
            if full_group not in hdf_file:
                raise MissingGroup(full_group)
            check_leaf_groups(group, month, hdf_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser(
        # use the docstring from the top of the file
        description=__doc__,
        # preserve the line breaks in the help text
        formatter_class=RawDescriptionHelpFormatter  
    )
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='Name of the HDF file')
    parsed = parser.parse_args() # uses sys.argv by default

    filename = parsed.filename
    print("Processing - " + filename)
    try:
        hdf_file = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
        check_hdf_structure(hdf_file)
    except (OSError, MissingGroup) as m:
        print(m)
    else:
        print("Basic structure of HDF file conforms to GFED4 format.")
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Usability

The program defines valid extensions like so:

> ```
> valid_extensions = ("hdf","hdf4","hdf5","h4","h5", "he2", "he5")
> ```

And then checks if an extension is valid like so:

> ```
> if path_string.split(".")[-1] in valid_extensions:
> ```

When checking if an extension is valid,
it might be a good idea to allow uppercase versions of the extensions too.
Or taking a lazier approach of allowing mixed-case values,
by writing the check as:

```
if path_string.split(".")[-1].lower() in valid_extensions:
```

#### Early returns

So-called *early returns* can reduce the nesting of code,
which can make it more readable.
For example instead of this:

> ```
> if path_string.split(".")[-1] in valid_extensions:
>     if Path(path_string).is_file():
>         return True
>     else:
>         print("\n'" + path_string + "' is not a valid file.\n")
>         return False
> else:
>     print("\nThe input file must be an HDF file with a correct extension.\n")
>     return False
> ```

You can write like this:

```
if path_string.split(".")[-1] in valid_extensions:
    if Path(path_string).is_file():
        return True
    print("\n'" + path_string + "' is not a valid file.\n")
    return False

print("\nThe input file must be an HDF file with a correct extension.\n")
return False
```

Other parts of the code can be similarly simplified.

#### Formatting strings

The `"%02d" % month` style formatting is old-fashioned,
the modern recommended way is using the `format` function of strings.
Instead of this:

> ```
> full_group = group + "/" + ("%02d" % month) + "/" + leaf
> ```

It would be better like this:

```
full_group = '{}/{:02d}/{}'.format(group, month, leaf)
```

#### Redundant parentheses

The parentheses are redundant in these examples,
and similarly at other places in the code:

> ```
> valid_extensions = ("hdf","hdf4","hdf5","h4","h5", "he2", "he5")
>
> for group in ("ancill/basis_regions", "lon", "lat"):
> ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review. With regard to the redundant parentheses, if I remove the braces which type of collection do they become implicitly? My intention with the braces here is to declare them tuples, and therefore immutable.

Comment: @RudiKershaw they will be tuples by default without the parens